# Backup of large database

Tags: php, mysql, export

My task is drop one database before take backup. In **nexcess** I have seen option for take partial backup but my problem is take backup of selected database.I have only a cpanel details. Please help me.

Comment: sounds like a cron with one "mysql_query("DROP STUFF") and mysqldump together with nice and ionice"

Comment: I haven't seen cron job option in nexcess

Comment: you have shell access?

Comment: No. But I have tried to run mysql command used with shell_exec() function in php.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Sypex Dumper](http://sypex.net/en/products/dumper/about/) for backup of large database.